Are "dinanzi" and "giuoco" more formal choices than "davanti" and "gioco"?
I've come across a passage in the piece Il perfetto amore (1910) by Roberto Bracco that uses the words dinanzi and giuoco instead of the more common davanti and gioco:

ATTO PRIMO. Il salotto di un piccolo albergo elegante. — Qualche
canapè, seggiole a sdraio, poltrone, poltroncine. Nel centro, una gran
tavola, su cui sono, bene ordinati, giornali, guide, riviste, orarii
di ferrovie. Quasi presso la parete sinistra, un po' di sbieco, un
pianoforte col dorso rivolto al muro. Dinanzi al pianoforte il
relativo sediolino senza spalliera. Verso lo stesso lato, un tavolino
con su un mazzo di carte francesi ed altri oggetti da giuoco.

I'm curious if these are considered more formal or literary choices in Italian. Can anyone shed some light on whether these words are used to convey a more refined tone or if they have any other specific connotations?

I'll add to Charo's answer that those are more old-fashioned than formal choices: if you used them nowadays, it would look more as if you tried to mimic Italian language from more than a century ago, than as if you wrote in an especially formal way. The spelling orarii (as opposite to orari) is quite rare today, too.

@DaG:  Since comments are designed to be temporary, if you don't mind, I've added this to my answer.

@Charo: Of course!

According to the vocabolario Treccani, giuoco is a literary variant of gioco.
The dizionario De Mauro uses what is called a marca d'uso. The word davanti in his more frequent adverbial use is marked as "FO", which means

FO: fondamentale; tra i lemmi principali, sono così marcati i vocaboli di altissima frequenza, le cui occorrenze costituiscono circa il 90% delle occorrenze lessicali nell’insieme di tutti i testi scritti o discorsi parlati;

That is,

FO: fundamental; among the main lemmas, the most frequently used words are marked in this way, whose occurrences constitute about 90% of the lexical occurrences in the entirety of all written texts or spoken discourse.

The adverbial and adjectival uses of dinanzi are marked as "CO", which means

CO: comune; sono così marcati i vocaboli che sono usati e compresi indipendentemente dalla professione o mestiere che si esercita o dalla collocazione regionale e che sono generalmente noti a chiunque abbia un livello mediosuperiore di istruzione;

That is,

CO: common; the words marked this way are used and understood regardless of one's profession or trade, or regional location, and are generally known to anyone with at least a high school level of education.

This means that dinanzi is less used than davanti, generally requires a certain level of instruction to be used and understood, but it hasn't a specialized usage, so it isn't restricted to literature.
In addition, as @DaG has said in a comment, both these words, giuoco and dinanzi,

are more old-fashioned than formal choices: if you used them nowadays, it would look more as if you tried to mimic Italian language from more than a century ago, than as if you wrote in an especially formal way.


Dinanzi e giuoco sono forme arcaiche, o meglio desuete, non più usate. Davanti e gioco sono equivalenti, ma sono quelli in uso oggi nel linguaggio corrente. Nota infatti che il testo in questione è datato 1910.
